# Windows equivalent of Linux ksu (Kerberized super-user) on windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, sudo, runas, kerberos

`ksu`, Kerberized super-user, command is able to use a credential cache file (i.e. containing Kerberos ticket for user *u1*) in order to execute a shell/command with user u1.

I have worked long time with Linux and now I'm moving to the Windows world and Active Directory domain.. I'm a total newbie. I have understood that, in Windows, credentials (Krb too) are managed and stored through the LSASS service, I have understood that the RunAs command performs a task that is similar to Linux *su/sudo* but providing username/password. I cannot find out a command to perform the same task with already acquired Krb credentials.

**Questions**

- In Windows, how can I execute a script in the name of another user by
  using acquired Krb tickets (stored in LSASS or other cache file)? Is there a command?
- Or.. Is there a way to do this programmatically with C#/Java?
- Or.. Is there a way to execute a shell script remotely with GSSAPI by providing a forwardable Krb ticket?

Being able to use Linux's like ccache files for credential..would be great.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there is no way to make it work in Windows in exactly the
same way.

A rather lame solution is to use the
[runas command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with the `/savecred` parameter.
This saves the password so it has to be entered only the first time the RunAs command is used, but is an extremely bad idea as it creates a gaping security hole. There is also the gotcha that it only works with the built-in 
Administrator account, disabled by default, which creates a second gaping security hole.

For details on making it work see
[How To Create a Shortcut That Lets a Standard User Run An Application as Administrator](https://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/).

I would really advise to use the RunAs command with user-name, and supply the
password at runtime.

For remote execution, see the [PsExec tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
for launching interactive command-prompts on remote systems.